# Can I put "cause" with "you embarrassment"?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> When these fears begin to ____ you embarrassment or you feel that your life is being disrupted then you would be wise to seek treatment for what could potentially be a phobia.

A) cause
B) make
C) create
D) give

I understood answer B (make) is not appropriate this sentence grammatically, but why is the answer A? As I know, "to cause" have to put with "someone + to verb" or only "noun"  but above these sentence it's not.
can you explain it for me?

Comment: Why do you think _embarrassment_ is not a noun? It falls under your _only noun_ "rule", but that "rule" is incomplete. The noun is the direct object, but _you_ is the indirect object. There is no reason why it could not be used.

Answer (score 1):

"Cause you embarrassment" is exactly the same structure as "give you the book", or "save you a seat".

In each case, it is an optional rearrangement of the form with an explicit preposition: "cause embarrassment to you"; "give the book to you"; "save a seat for you". There is no difference in meaning between the two forms.

This construction is regular with ditransitive verbs (which have a direct and an indirect object). The preposition omitted is always either "to" or "for".

Answer (score 0):

You can use both structures:

> cause *[somebody]* + to *[infinitive]*
>
> cause *[somebody]* *[something]*

So you can say:

> **cause** you embarrassment.
>
> **cause** you **to feel** embarrassed.

But you cannot say:

> **make** you embarrassment
>
> **create** you embarrassment

However, you can say:

> make you feel embarrassed.